# Is "and" necessary before the last item in the list of things after "such as"?

Tags: conjunctions

Could someone tell me whether "and" is necessary in the space:

```
I like different types of fruits, such as apples, oranges, bananas, [and] pineapples.
```

Comment: I see. So you mean "not" can be omitted for rhetorical use. Interesting, though I think it is more formal with the "and".

Comment: It sometimes happens that informal usages converge with established rhetorical ones. What would you think of 'I came, I saw, and I conquered'?